# Не меняется индикатор прогресса в Прогресс баре. QML, связанное с Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, progress-bar

У меня есть прогресс бар в QML. Который после изменения значений, индикатор прогресса не меняет. Сигналы проходят, в консоле выводятся должные значения:

```
qml: onSignalQMLValueProgressBar 6
qml: Progressbar value changed:  5
qml: Progressbar value changed:  5
qml: onSignalQMLValueProgressBar 5
qml: Progressbar value changed:  0
qml: onSignalQMLValueProgressBar 0
```

Сам код:

```
ViewshedGeoElement.qml
    ...
        SceneView {
            id: sceneView
            objectName: "sceneView"
            anchors.fill: parent
            signal signalQMLSizeProgressBar()
            signal signalQMLValueProgressBar()
            property bool checked : true
            property var myObject: ({})
            onTaskedClicked: {
            onSignalQMLSizeProgressBar: {
                console.log("onSignalQMLValueProgressBar",progressBarSize());
                progressbar_id.minimumValue = 0;
                progressbar_id.maximumValue = progressBarSize();
                progressbar_id.value = 0;
            }
            onSignalQMLValueProgressBar: {
                console.log("onSignalQMLValueProgressBar",setValueProgressBar());
                progressbar_id.value = setValueProgressBar();
            }
        }

    ...
                        ProgressBar {
                            id: progressbar_id
                            width: parent.width
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter // horizontally align the progress bar

                            minimumValue: 0    // don't know what editorScene is
                            maximumValue: 100    // so I'm using raw values
                            value: 5

                            onValueChanged: {
                                console.log("Progressbar value changed: ", progressbar_id.value)
                            }
                            onVisibleChanged: {
                                // side note: I'm not getting any output from this handler
                                console.log("Progressbar visibility chanaged: ", progressbar_id.visible)
                            }
                        }
    ...
```

Код Qt:

```
ViewshedGeoElement.h
...
    Q_INVOKABLE int progressBarSize();
    Q_INVOKABLE int setValueProgressBar();
...
signals:
    void signalSizeProgressBar();
    void signalValueProgressBar();
...
private:
    int SizeProgressBar = 0;
    int ValueProgressBar = 0;
```

ViewshedGeoElement.cpp

```
...  
                QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(signalSizeProgressBar()),m_sceneView,SIGNAL(signalQMLSizeProgressBar()));
            QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(signalValueProgressBar()),m_sceneView,SIGNAL(signalQMLValueProgressBar()));
...
int ViewshedGeoElement::progressBarSize()
 {
   return SizeProgressBar;
 }

 int ViewshedGeoElement::setValueProgressBar()
 {
   return ValueProgressBar;
 }
 ...
    void ViewshedGeoElement::dbLoadRealTimeFormulars(QString variantId)
    {
        QStringList ListStringJSON;
        //    for (int i=1; i<=4;i++)
        //    {
        pkori::db::qtconnect::QtDBConn qtConn("DB_DAOMODEL_CONNECTION_NAME");

        //    QSqlQuery queryModel3D("SELECT * FROM movie.model3d WHERE uid=144 ;",qtConn.database("DB_DAOMODEL_CONNECTION_NAME"));
        QSqlQuery queryModel3D("SELECT * FROM movie.model3d;",qtConn.database("DB_DAOMODEL_CONNECTION_NAME"));

        // int fieldNoID = queryModel3D.record().indexOf("id");
        // int fieldNoFullName = queryModel3D.record().indexOf("fullname");

        int fieldNoObvpID = queryModel3D.record().indexOf("obvpid");
        int fieldNoUID = queryModel3D.record().indexOf("uid");

        while (queryModel3D.next())
        {
            //        qDebug() << "=======================queryModel3D==================";
            //        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << queryModel3D.value(fieldNoObvpID).toString();
            //        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << queryModel3D.value(fieldNoUID).toString();
            //        qDebug() << "=======================queryModel3D==================";

            QString queryStr = (QString("SELECT * from movie.realposition1 WHERE"
                                        " movie.realposition1.variantdataid = %1"
                                        " AND uid = "+queryModel3D.value(fieldNoUID).toString()+""
                                                                                                " AND obvpid = "+queryModel3D.value(fieldNoObvpID).toString()+" "
                                                                                                                                                              " order by realtime;").arg(variantId));

            QSqlQuery query(queryStr,qtConn.database("DB_DAOMODEL_CONNECTION_NAME"));
            //    if (!query.exec(queryStr)) {
            //        qDebug() << "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " << query.lastQuery();
            //        printQueryValue(query);
            //        query.clear();
            //        return;
            //    }
            int fieldID               = query.record().indexOf("id");
            int fieldVariantDataID    = query.record().indexOf("variantdataid");
            int fieldObvpID           = query.record().indexOf("obvpid");
            int fieldxdID             = query.record().indexOf("xdid");
            int fieldRealtime         = query.record().indexOf("realtime");
            int fieldX                = query.record().indexOf("x");
            int fieldY                = query.record().indexOf("y");
            int fieldH                = query.record().indexOf("h");
            int fielduID              = query.record().indexOf("uid");
            int fieldDirection        = query.record().indexOf("mvmntdirection");
            int fieldVelocity         = query.record().indexOf("mvmntvelocity");

            QString dataStringJSON = "{ \"coordinates\":[";
            int n = 1;
            SizeProgressBar = query.size();
            emit signalSizeProgressBar();
            ValueProgressBar = 0;
            emit signalValueProgressBar();
            while (query.next()) {
                //            qDebug() << n;
                //            qDebug() << "=======================query==================";
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldID).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldVariantDataID).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldObvpID).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldxdID).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldRealtime).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldX).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldY).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldH).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fielduID).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldDirection).toString();
                //            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << query.value(fieldVelocity).toString();
                //            qDebug() << "=======================query==================";
                double x = query.value(fieldX).toDouble();
                //                x=x+i+200;
                double y = query.value(fieldY).toDouble();
                //                y=y+i+200;
                int answer = pkori::roocore::coordconvertor::convertPlane42ToWgs84Grad( &x, &y);
                dataStringJSON += "{\"ID\":\""            +query.value(fieldID).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"variantdataid\":\""  +query.value(fieldVariantDataID).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"obvpid\":\""         +query.value(fieldObvpID).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"xdid\":\""           +query.value(fieldxdID).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"X\":\""              +QString::number(x, 'f', 6)+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"Y\":\""              +QString::number(y, 'f', 6)+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"H\":\""              +query.value(fieldH).toString()+"\",";
                //                dataStringJSON += "\"uid\":\""            +QString::number(query.value(fielduID).toInt()+i*100)+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"uid\":\""            +query.value(fielduID).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"mvmntdirection\":\"" +query.value(fieldDirection).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"mvmntvelocity\":\""  +query.value(fieldVelocity).toString()+"\",";
                dataStringJSON += "\"zone\":\""           +QString::number(answer)+"\",";
                if (query.size()==n)
                {
                    dataStringJSON += "\"Date\":\"" +query.value(fieldRealtime).toString()+"\"}";
                } else {
                    dataStringJSON += "\"Date\":\"" +query.value(fieldRealtime).toString()+"\"},";
                }
                n++;
                ValueProgressBar = n;
                emit signalValueProgressBar();
            }
            dataStringJSON +="]}";
            ListStringJSON.append(dataStringJSON);
        }
        //    }
        changeMission(variantId,ListStringJSON);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде не понятно, какой сигнал кидает сообщение в консоль

```
qml: onSignalQMLValueProgressBar 0
```

т.к. и в `onSignalQMLSizeProgressBar`, и в `onSignalQMLValueProgressBar` в `console.log(...)` фигурирует текст *"onSignalQMLValueProgressBar"*. Если в случае с `onSignalQMLSizeProgressBar`, то понятно - там `value` обнуляется.

Лучше б `setValueProgressBar` переименовать во что-то типа `maxValueProgressBar`, а то слово `set` сразу наводит на мысль, что надо что-то присвоить, а в итоге просто возвращается значение.

Также обращаю внимание, что у `ProgressBar` значения `value, minimumValue, maximumValue`  имеют тип с плавающей точкой.

Рабочий пример. Попробуйте сопоставить со своим кодом.

Класс, где реализована логика вычислений:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float progress READ progress NOTIFY progressChanged)

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void start()
    {
        QTimer* t = new QTimer(this);
        connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [this]() {
            m_progress += 0.3f;
            emit progressChanged(m_progress);
        });
        t->start(1000);
    }

    float progress()
    {
        return m_progress;
    }

signals:
    void progressChanged(float progress);

private:
    float m_progress;
};
```

Кастомный прогресс-бар, PBar.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ProgressBar {
    id: prg
    minimumValue: 0
    maximumValue: 3
    value: 0.3

    Connections {
        target: worker
        onProgressChanged: {
            prg.value = progress;
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.top: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent
        text: qsTr("Старт")
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                worker.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В main.cpp добавить

```
Worker worker;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("worker", &worker);
```

Comment: спасибо позже проверю . Сейчас нет возможности